# Send object via TCP/IP

Tags: c#, sockets, object, tcp

everybody. I've got very simple and not once repeated question :) The main idea is:
I have to send object of class/structure described by me via TCP/IP using C#. I've been succeed using TCPListener and TCPClient classes and was able to send messages (strings). But after I start to practice with serialization and etc. my successful experience ends. I've read a lot of stuff before writing here, really, even something about marshalling option and other strange stuff, but i don't understand it, and i think it's not needed. So, what I ask from U guys, it would be so pleasure, if U give me an example.

Class example:

```
[SERIALIZABLE]
public class SomeClass
{
   public SomeClass(){}

   private int SomeIntData;
   private Int32 SomeInt32Data;
   private Double SomeDoubleData;
}
```

Please, show me how to send object of this class SomeClass via tcp/ip. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if you are using WCF or not, but in WCF to send business objects across the wire, the contracts have to be shared between the client and the server in terms of wsdl file.

Comment: I assume there is some reason why you are rolling this your self and not using some RPC / remoting framework eg WCF?

Comment: There is a system like a radar system. And a server part is already exist. I need to remake old client part and put variables, which I want to have from output object, in new way. And I don't want to remake all the stuff, just some stuff on client part like socket and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `[Serializable]` attribute to it, and then format it using a [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx)

Use `Serialize` to serialize the object into a stream, and `Deserialize` to create it on the other side.

Comment: The problem is I've never worked with network connections before. How to serialize I now. But it would be awesome if u give me example of code, which describes putting object into stream, and receiving it. Would it be OK if i do `stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);`, where `data` is serialized object?

Comment: You serialize directly into a stream - you pass the stream to Serialize. You don't need to do anything else.